# how can I get the URL variable in modx gallery

Tags: gallery, modx, modx-revolution

I installed modx gallery and I want to link to the URL I type in when I upload new pictures on the backend. I tried to customize the template but can't find the URL-variable from the upload form:

http://rtfm.modx.com/display/ADDON/Gallery.Gallery.thumbTpl

How would I do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The placeholder for the URL is [[+url]].
So, call

```
[[!Gallery &album=`1` &thumbTpl=`myThumbTplChunk`]]
```

and create chunk called "myThumbTplChunk" with this code:

```
<div class="[[+cls]]">
    <a href="[[+url]]">
        <img class="[[+imgCls]]" src="[[+thumbnail]]" alt="[[+name]]" />
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: My God! Thank you! But where did you find that info? I don't see it anywhere in the documentation!